# How to write drop down menu data to MySQL Database

Tags: php, html

Currently trying to write data from my dropdown menu to a field on my database. All the text fields are populating perfectly, but not sure why the drop down data isn't.

[This is my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPRSW.png)

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: Your code should be posted as text within the question itself, not as an externally-linked image.

Comment: There is no `name="returned"` in your html. You are using that in your php, which is why it fails. Add that to the `select` tag

Comment: and now to get my magnifying glass. Post text-based code and NOT an "image of".

Comment: and why did this question receive an upvote in the first place??

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid syntax here.

```
$returned = $_POST['returned']; // This returns null.
```

You can always change your `loans` table of the `$returned` field to **nullable**.

**OR**, you can just fix it by replacing..

```
<select>
  <option value="No"> No </option>
  <option value="Yes"> Yes</option>
</select>
```

To

```
<select name="returned">
  <option value="No"> No </option>
  <option value="Yes"> Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, that sorted it

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<select>` tag to this

```
<select name="returned">
...
</select>
```

you have to give the name of the parameter